# PHP script with parse cloud database

Tags: php, parse-platform, cloud

I am getting the following error while running:

```
'Parse\ParseException' with message 'Couldn't resolve host 'api.parse.com'' in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Coupid/parsesdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:258 
    Stack trace: 
        #0 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Coupid/parsesdk/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php(305): Parse\ParseClient::_request('GET', '/1/classes/Coup...', NULL, NULL, false) 
        #1 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Coupid/parsesdk/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php(248): Parse\ParseQuery->find(false) 
        #2 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Coupid/parsesdk/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php(70): Parse\ParseQuery->first(false) 
        #3 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Coupid/getAppId.php(20): Parse\ParseQuery->get('npwZuRB4DL') 
        #4 {main}
```